# How to tell which functions and constants are exposed in the MATLAB interface of jeromq

Tags: java, matlab, zeromq

I am using jeromq (jeromq-0.5.2.jar) inside MATLAB (R2018a).
I can open sockets and send and receive data.
I want to make my code as robust as possible, so am using Req/Rep sockets, and want to set various socket options, and use non blocking recv etc.
I have downloaded the JD Java decompiler and can see all the function and class code inside the jeromq jar.

My question is: How do I know the function signatures and constants made available to MATLAB code from the jeromq jar?

For example say I want to set a socket option, to force linger time to zero, or a socket option to immediate.
I would also like to use an 0mq polling option to test if there is data on a socket before doing receive.

I see the packages `org.zeromq` and `zmq` inside the jar.
It seems the context we create is an `org.zeromq.zContext` object
and the socket we create from that is a `ZMQ$Socket` object.

Is there any easy way to look inside the decompiled Java and see where all the exported functions are, and the exported constants?